# Chrome extension: Problem with OAuth Verification Request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I have a problem with the Video oauth Verification Request, i sent the video for the verification and they answered me with this email.

```
Unfortunately, we found that your YouTube demo video isn't detailed enough. The video doesn't show  the client id (please see the attached screen shot)

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
View metadata for files in your Google Drive
Reply to this email and provide a YouTube link to a new demo video that shows, in detail:

How to log into your project. 
Make sure that the URL bar with the client ID is clearly visible.
How to request an OAuth token on the OAuth Consent Screen/Permissions Page.
How your project uses the scope listed above.
Read the OAuth 2.0 Scopes page for information on scopes.
Thank you for patience.
```

I honestly don't know what to do, I saw a video on youtube where the user logs in with his gmail account and you see the url address with the client id but in my case not. When I try to log in a pop-up without url address opens.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, i wrote to Google saying that I use the getAuthToken function and they accepted the request